# Return the index at which an element is first found in a list - Python

Tags: python, list, indexing, integer, element

I need to write a function ind(e, L), which takes in a list L and an element e. The function ind() should return the index at which e is first found in L. Counting begins at 0. If e is not an element of L, then ind(e, L) should return the integer equal to len(L).

This is what I have so far:

```
def ind(e, L):
    if e in L:
        return [L].index('e')
    if e not in L: 
        return len[L]
```

Can someone help me please because I can't figure it out!

Comment: Do **not** edit your question to ask a new one, once you have attracted answers. Instead, ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do some changes.

- remove square brackets which exists around `L`.
- remove the quotes which exists around `e`, since `e` is a variable not value.
- Add `try`, `except` block.

Code:

```
>>> def ind(e, L):
        try: 
            return L.index(e) 
        except ValueError: 
            return len(L)


>>> ind(3, [1,2])
2
>>> ind(3, [1,2,3,4,3])
2
>>> ind('r', ['a'])
1
>>> ind('r', ['a', 'r'])
1
>>>
```

Comment: This is inefficient... `try: return L.index(e) except ValueError: return len(L)` would be *much* better.

Comment: @vaultah even your comment is optimized: the `try` serves a dual purpose (english and python) :D

Comment: @AvinashRaj that `else` is completely useless and you still perform the search twice.

Comment: @vaultah I tested the execution time of the two approaches, which showing the `try-catch` is slower when exception caught, why? see my answer below

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Avinash's answer, I suggest using a [tenary conditional operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) to be a bit brief:

```
In [25]: def ind(e, L):
    ...:     return L.index(e) if e in L else len(L)

In [26]: lst=[1,2]

In [27]: ind(2, lst)
Out[27]: 1

In [28]: ind(33, lst)
Out[28]: 2
```

Or try what @vaultah commented:

```
In [43]: def ind2(e, L):
    ...:     try: 
    ...:         return L.index(e) 
    ...:     except ValueError: 
    ...:         return len(L)
    ...:
```

To benchmark:

```
In [65]: s='Python is a dynamic and strongly typed programming language that is designed to emphasize usability. Two similar but incompatible versions of Python are in widespread use (2 and 3). Please consider using [python-2.7] or [python-3.x] tags for version-specific questions about Python.'

In [66]: lst=list(s)

In [67]: %timeit ind('r', lst)
The slowest run took 6.81 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 989 ns per loop

In [68]: %timeit ind2('r', lst)
The slowest run took 5.01 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 640 ns per loop

In [69]: lst2=list(s.replace('r', '')) #remove all 'r's in the list

In [70]: %timeit ind('r', lst2)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.77 µs per loop

In [71]: %timeit ind2('r', lst2)
The slowest run took 4.12 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.61 µs per loop

In [72]:
```

**Note** that the `try-except` logic is not always more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Or, without introducing exception handling or calling out to Python's own list.index method:

```
def ind(e, L):
    for index, item in enumerate(L):
        if item == e:
             return index

    return index+1
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
def ind(e, L):
    if e in L:
        return L.index(e)
    if e not in L: 
        return len (L)
```